# Why are Woocommerce product names showing the word line [line] in square brackets after?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

As the title suggests, can anyone please advise why Woocommerce is showing the word line in square brackets '[line]' after the product names?

Please see the image below:

[image: Image of product names with text in square brackets after]

I am using the latest version of WordPress (3.8.1), the Yith SoCute theme and Woocommerce with the following plugins:

- Wow Slider
- Woocommerce Compare
- Woocommerce Ajax Navigation
- Woocommerce Wish List
- Woocommerce Magnifier

I think that there may be a simple explanation for this which I am missing; however, I can't find any answers using Google and, I have now spent far too much time looking (a full day).

So, it's time to ask for help.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you disabled all of those plugins to see if it is still there?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Howlin.  Yes, it's one of the first things that I tried.  The test site is here if it helps: http://crystal.byethost14.com.  Please navigate to the shop and then click on an image to reveal issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[Line]` is been added to the page by this piece of code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', create_function( '', 'echo do_shortcode("[line]");' ) );
```

in the `woocommerce/content-single-product.php` file

to remove the `[line]` you do one of two things:

1. Change that piece of code to

   ```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', create_function( '', 'echo do_shortcode("&nbsp;");' ) );
   ```
2. Remove/comment out that line, but in doing that you will need to add `clear:left;` to the `.single-product.woocommerce div.product .description` style:

   ```
   .single-product.woocommerce div.product .description
   {
       margin-top: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 20px;
       clear: left;
   }
   ```

   otherwise the description will come onto the same line as the product title.

Comment: Thanks @Howlin; I'll try your advice when I switch back on and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Your 1st suggestion worked great thanks.  One last question please: Do you know whether [line] was an error or is something supposed to go there such as a promotional image or something?